# How to get maximum double value from ParsedMax elasticseearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I older version of Elasticsearch 5.x, we used the class [ParsedMax.getValue()](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/5.6.8/org/elasticsearch/search/aggregations/metrics/max/ParsedMax.html#getValue--) method to get maximum  Double value from the object as follows

```
Double val = Double.valueOf(parsedMax.getValue());
```

Now, we are upgrading to the newer elasticsearch version 8.3.3 and we found this method doesn't exists. How can we achieve this in newer version

Comment: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/latest/org.elasticsearch.server/org/elasticsearch/search/aggregations/metrics/ParsedSingleValueNumericMetricsAggregation.html#value()

Comment: @Rpj does the link posted in the previous comment help?

Answer (score 0):

I think that in version 8.3.3, the method changed from getValue() to value().

The class [ParsedMax](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/8.3.3/org.elasticsearch.server/org/elasticsearch/search/aggregations/metrics/ParsedMax.html) now inherits from the class: [ParsedSingleValueNumericMetricsAggregation](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/8.3.3/org.elasticsearch.server/org/elasticsearch/search/aggregations/metrics/ParsedSingleValueNumericMetricsAggregation.html) which uses the interface [NumericMetricsAggregation.SingleValue](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/8.3.3/org.elasticsearch.server/org/elasticsearch/search/aggregations/metrics/NumericMetricsAggregation.SingleValue.html) which has the method value().